# How do you append a value to an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

In **Javascript**

```
> var arr = new Array();
> arr.push("Hello");
```

In **Ruby**

```
> first_array = ["Matz", "Guido"]
> first_array << "Yukihiro"
```

In **Python**

```
> array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'example']
> li.append("new")
```

It seems to me that it is not as simple as the examples above. How might one do it with **C++**?

Comment: How did you create your array?

Comment: The Python example uses a list, not an array (that's why it says `li.append`).

Answer (score 3):

Those are high-level languages, and C++ is not one of them. Arrays in C++ contain the dimension as part of their type, and thus their dimension cannot be changed at runtime.

A "workaround" is to use dynamically-allocated blocks of memory instead of arrays, and it's advisable to get used to wrappers around this facility, such as `std::vector`.

Comment: +1 although your answer seems non-obvious to me (in reference to the comment you left on the question).

Comment: In which way is C++ not a high-level language? Just because the array class is spelled `std::vector<T>` rather than `T[n]` doesn't mean it is somehow not a high-level language!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: `std::vector<T>` is not "the array class". And I don't consider that the inclusion of a library of functions and types that are written in the language makes the core language itself any lower- or higher-level. Ultimately, though, "high-level" is a relative term.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Any decent C++ book will cover this sort of thing pretty early on. I think it's clear that no research was performed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `std::vector`, but -1 for saying C++ is not a high-level language.  I believe anything above assembly is a high-level language.

Comment: @Thomas: Your belief is your prerogative. Mine differs.

Answer (score 1):

- C++ doesn't have the dynamic array data type by default
- The easiest solution is to use an `std::vector`:

  ```
  std::vector<int> data;
  data.push_back(5);
  ```

Comment: Arguably, `std::vector` is a "dynamic array data type", and the standard library is available "by default". :P It's not a built-in type, though.

Answer (score -1):

If you need at any cost an array to do this, you need to resize your array, because the size is fixed when you create your array.
Resize an array is a solution that, personally, I don't like. You have to create a new array a2 with a size "a1.lenght + 1", then copy all your value to the old array into the new one, and add your new value.
Consider to use a std::vector, that has the append function (push_back) and doesn't has a fixed size.